# How to make Windows Explorer preview panel to show LibreOffice files preview?

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, libreoffice

On my work, Windows Explorer can show preview of Microsoft Office documents using Windows Explorer's preview panel (View > Press "preview panel" icon and select a Microsoft Office file). That computer has Microsoft Office 2010 and Windows 10, 10240 update.

But on my computer I have Windows 10, 10586.63 update with LibreOffice 4.4.5.2, and I cannot preview .DOC or .XLS files, nor .ODT or .ODS files on Windows Explorer's preview panel.

Comment: http://www.pcworld.com/article/257238/i_cant_preview_office_files.html  there is some helpful information to help you get going not putting this as an answer just some help.

Comment: use the free [Word Viewer]
(https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=4) and [Excel Viewer] (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=10). they're free and will preview your files, and you can open them with whatever you want.

Comment: @MaherFattouh I added Word and Excel viewers from Microsoft links you gave us. Ok, they open DOC and XLS files, as LibreOffice does. My question is about previewing them through Preview Pane of File Explorer. Now I have installed on my machine the thosse viewers you passed me and the LibreOffice, but File Explorer continues without previewing DOC and XLS files, nor ODT or ODS... :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid, it isn't possible at the moment, because there is no extension developed yet. You can keep track of the development here: https://bz.apache.org/ooo/show_bug.cgi?id=107602 (and vote on the issue, to receive more attention)

However, there is a possibility, that may seams a little odd. It is, in my eyes, an overkill, but could be worth a shot, if you really want it. As it turns out, Microsoft Office has a preview handler for .odt files, so you could install MS Office (to preview the files) and still use Libre Office to open/edit them. You could download the test version from here: https://products.office.com/en-us/try (adjust the en-us stuff to your own locale, if you like), install it and I think it should work that way. Unfortunately I don't have a Win 10 machine to test it and I'm not sure, what happens after the testing period. My guess would be, that you can't open Word any more, but the preview handler shouldn't be affected by this.

Comment: Best answer, although I could not solve the issue.

Comment: "you could install MS Office"  ;-)  If MS Office were installed, the problem wouldn't exist and OP wouldn't be asking this question (he wants to preview .DOC and .XLS, but LibreOffice doesnt shows them in preview pane, either). Maybe he doesn't want to pay for MS Office.

Answer (score 2):

The Preview in Windows Explorer is handled by add-ons, which are little programs
that declare themselves to Explorer so it knows to load them when encountering
a matching file-type.

Unfortunately, Microsoft supplies add-ons for only a few most-used file-types,
leaving the work for other file-types to the companies that invented them.

LibreOffice has not (maybe just yet) supplied such an add-on.
One must then depend on third-party software for furnishing them.

The only product I know of that does the Preview for LibreOffice is
[Quick View Plus Standard Edition](http://www.avantstar.com/quick-view-plus-standard-edition), which unfortunately is commercial
software, $49 with a 30-day trial version.
It is advertised as compatible with Windows 10 and integrating with
Windows Explorer, Internet Explorer 8, 9 and 10 (probably forgot to add 11),
Microsoft Outlook (Express), Firefox and more.
It cannot integrate with Edge, since at the moment Edge doesn't have add-ons.
(I have no experience with this product.)

Comment: Ok, it solves, but only for 30 days free :(

Comment: Also it does not uninstall correctely >:@ Why didn't I create a restore point before installed it? Now it does not preview none, nor TXT files :(

Comment: Get in touch with their Support. Strange - most installations create a restore point before starting.

Comment: A bounty of -50 to you :D

Comment: After uninstalling that QuickView Plus - if you could do it -, to restore preview pane functionality, you must delete all `{8895b1c6-b41f-4c1c-a562-0d564250836f}` entries inside a key inside ShellEx on regedit - ALLLLLLL XD. To do it, you must use regedit.exe from Windows 10 10240 version, not 10586 (1511) one, because it is buggy on search........... I hate W10 :/

Comment: I came to this question with exactly the same problem that OP (Win10 + MS Office at work, Win10 + LibreOffice at home, and intending to see LibreOffice docs in preview pane). I hate W10 too !   :-)

Answer (score 2):

Although I do not actually use it, I have Microsoft Office 2007 installed simply because it has built in preview handlers.  My default office suite is Libreoffice and what I do, for compatablity reasons because most people use MS Office, is save all my files in Office 97/2000 format.  That allows the preview handler for MS Office to preview the files thinking they are Word, Excel, Powerpoint documents and other people to open them should I have need to send one by email.